# Can I define a default profile for snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

From the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles), I know that I can define a profile and use it via

```
snakemake --profile <name>
```

Can I make one of these profiles the default (to be used when I enter
the command `snakemake`)?

Defining an alias in .bashrc would be a workaround. However, I wondered whether there is an 'official' snakemake solution.

Sideremark: My initial motivation for a default profile of snakemake was to define
the default number of cores, so that I would not always have to type

```
snakemake -j [cores]
```

The default number of cores is "None" (for my installation of snakemake using conda).

Comment: If someone can confirm that there is no possibility to define a default snakemake profile, I will also accept this as an answer. It is also good to know if there is no snakemake solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles):

> The default profile to use when no `--profile` argument is specified can also be set via the environment variable `SNAKEMAKE_PROFILE`, e.g. by specifying export `SNAKEMAKE_PROFILE=myprofile` in your `~/.bashrc` or the system wide shell defaults.

Comment: Thanks! The environment variable `SNAKEMAKE_PROFILE` was introduced in version [6.5.0 on 2021-06-22](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html#id213) (probably by coincidence, a month after I posed the question). 
The explanation was added to the documentation [on 2022-08-25 in version 7.13.0](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html#id41).

Answer (score -1):

[Description of `--profile` option](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#EXECUTION):

> --profile
> Name of profile to use for configuring Snakemake. Snakemake will search for a corresponding folder in /etc/xdg/snakemake and /home/docs/.config/snakemake. Alternatively, this can be an absolute or relative path. The profile folder has to contain a file ‘config.yaml’. This file can be used to set default values for command line options in YAML format. For example, ‘–cluster qsub’ becomes ‘cluster: qsub’ in the YAML file. Profiles can be obtained from https://github.com/snakemake-profiles.

If your profile is located under `/etc/xdg/snakemake` or `/home/docs/.config/snakemake`, snakemake will automatically utilize them.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually tried this already. As the text indicates, placing my profile in these folders (which differ from system to system) only allows to reuse a standard profile (say `myprofile`) with the command `snakemake --profile myprofile`. However, snakemake does not  automatically utilize the profile, when I enter the command `snakemake`.

Comment: This does not answer the question but merely states how to *use* a profile. The question is whether one can set a **default** profile that is used *even without specifying `--profile`